# What does 'ground' look like on a breadboard?

Tags: circuit-design, ground, breadboard

Given the following circuit:

[image]

What would this look like on a breadboard? For example, what is 'ground' on the right? Is there a particular 'component' that can be used in a breadboard to act as ground (I'm usually using a 9V battery as the voltage source).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember having similar confusion when first introduced to circuits. There is really not much to it..

The grounds on the left and right need to be connected together. In schematics, they are often split, for convenience and clarity.

For the 9V battery, the negative terminal would typically be used as ground. However, you could also connect two batteries in series and use the mid-point as ground to get -9V to +9V supply. In other words, ground can be anything you choose, it is just a "reference point".

[image]

[Image source](http://www.physics.utah.edu/~jui/3620-6620/y2009m02d03/741.html)

Comment: Could you provide a link or a citation for the graphic you used in your answer? We want to be sure to give credit to the original creator.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I added a link. This image is shared online quite a lot, but I think I found the *original* source...

Comment: Thanks, and have a +1.

Answer (score 2):

The GND symbol is not a component as much as it is a label or net name. Ground is just a conductor, an electrical node we designate as zero or the reference potential for our circuit.

Those two ground symbols  are the same point. You could just replace them with wire that all connects to each other. It's just messy and difficult actually draw wires everywhere if you have 50 connections to ground in your circuit. Also difficult to read if you have to follow a long trace that seems to run everywhere just to find that everything else ends up there too without shedding additional light onto the circuit section you were following since you already reached its end bit didn't realize it because it wasn't labelled.

Comment: would that mean then I could wire all the 'ground' symbols to the negative terminal of the battery, or what does that look like exactly?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: @David542 You wire all "ground" symbols to each other. You don't wire them to the negative terminal of the battery, unless the schematic says so. This schematic says so. Maybe on a different schematic, ground would be the positive terminal, or the output of an op-amp.

Answer (score 1):

On a breadboard, I tend to use the bottom one of the long common rails as the ground or common terminal.

This is because ground tends to be the terminal with most components connected to it. If you connect meters, or 'scopes, or signal generators, you usually need one connection to the ground terminal. Using a long trace gives plenty of points at which to make the connection, and I like to be able to identify quickly where it is.

Often, if a circuit doesn't include a long line at the bottom labelled 'ground', it's trivial to add one in, lining to all the ground symbols. Then the breadboard can be built to look like a copy of the schematic, as far as that's possible, to help with component identification.

One the one hand, ground is 'just' a named node, and doesn't need any particular treatment. It certainly does not need to be connected to an external ground like an earth spike or the safety ground in the mains wiring.

One the other hand, ground does tend to be a special node. It tends to be the largest, so stray capacitances from other nodes will be larger to the ground node than to others, which might make a difference in RF circuits, and even stability in lower frequency circuits built with fast components.

Comment: thanks for this. Would you be able to include a screenshot of an example breadboard that's 'wired' this way?